# Add custom signature by button to end of letter outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I have button with this macros:

```
Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Html_1()     
    Dim strbody As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    strbody = "custom signature"
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .Display 
        .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
    End With
End Sub
```

But this create a new msg, and I need first to write some text in blank letter  and next add one or more custom signature to end of the letter. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any special property or method for signatures. They are just a part of the message body. So, you can use the same properties you use for editing or setting the message bodies. The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

It is up to you which way is to choose, in case of the HTMLBody property you need to find the closing `</body>` tag and insert your valid signature HTML markup before it (for newly created items).

P.S. There is no need to create a new Application instance if you run the code in Outlook. Instead, you need to use the Application property.